# Update center missing from Sitecore launchpad

Tags: upgrade, update-packages, setup

I'm trying to upgrade Sitecore from 9.0.2 to 9.3 version, but there is no Update Center on the Launchpad.

- IIS is configured to allow access to the /sitecore/admin folder
- Sitecore Update Installation Wizard was updated through Control panel/Install a package

PackageManagementServiceUrl added to ConnectionStrings.config:

```
<add name="PackageManagementServiceUrl" connectionString="https://updatecenter.cloud.sitecore.net/" />
```

It looks like everything that is required in [the official documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/the-update-center.html) to use the Update Center is done, and it is suitable for the current version of Sitecore 9.0.2 but:

- there is no Update Center on the Launchpad
- requests to /sitecore/shell/client/applications/updatecenter nonstop request
  https://mywebsite.dev.local/sitecore/api/ssc/updatecenter/updatemode/-/UpdateModeState?sc_site=shell which returns 401 Unauthorized

I perform these actions as a user with administrator rights

Сan it be installed separately? Other options? Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Sitecore using Update Center is not the recommended way.

That's the reason why Sitecore removed the Update Center in Sitecore 10.1.0

**Sitecore Update Center -**
The Sitecore Update Center has been deprecated in Sitecore XP 10.1.0. The last version that you can use the Update Center with is Sitecore XP 10.0.X.

Comment: And what is the recommended way? 

I saw the Upgrade Center is recommended in official upgrade guide

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that the Update Center is a convenient feature for minor updates and patches, major version upgrades like the one you're attempting usually require a more comprehensive approach.

As @Vlad pointed out, relying solely on the Update Center might not suffice for a seamless upgrade. Instead, here's a more robust approach that's commonly followed by Sitecore developers:

- Install a Fresh new Sitecore Instance (in your case it is 9.3)
- Upgrade the Solution Codebase to be compatible with the new version of Sitecore. This involves updating .NET framework versions, Sitecore DLLs, and any dependent modules such as Unicorn or other third-party integrations.
- Take backups of your databases from the old Sitecore instance. Follow the [official documentation](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/103/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_103.aspx) to upgrade these databases to be compatible with the new Sitecore version.
- Attach Upgraded Databases to new Instances.
- Deploy the upgraded codebase to the root of your new Sitecore instance.
- Thoroughly test your application on the Sitecore 9.3 instance.